# Dynamically changing height of div in another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to allow the height of the div to dynamically change according to the number of elements inside the div. The whole idea of what i am trying to do is shown in the diagram below[image]

The last div should be able to change dynamically. It seems that i have to set the height of the third inner div. If i don't, the div appears outside the main div.

Solutions that i have tried:

1) overflow: auto

2) trying not setting the height of the 3rd inner div.

Must i use javascript? can i don't use javascript? These solutions didn't work. Need some guidance.. Sorry if the question was repeated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now i think you should this

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <div class="one">One</div>
     <div class="one">two</div>
  </div>

   <div class="child1">
    <div class="one">One</div>
     <div class="one">two</div>
  </div>


   <div class="child2">
     dynamic height
     </div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
.parent{
border:solid 1px red;
}
.child1, .child2{
overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
  border:solid 2px green;
}

.one{
background:red;
  border:solid 1px black;
  padding:10px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
```

**Live demo**  http://tinkerbin.com/i1R8emEb

Now change to height width or height  according to  your design ..

Comment: the technique is to use overflow: hidden is it?

Comment: yes if you remove border div than used to overflow : hidden to clear parent div this is collapse margin

Comment: didn't understand the last statement

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the div a fixed height, just use `float:left;` in your CSS.

Comment: With float:left the CSS do all this in one thing: `display: block; width: xxxpx; height xxpx;` (dynamically changes the height)